# handsontable select editor - how to have both value and text?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

[handsontable - Demo](http://handsontable.com/demo/selectEditor.html)

In the example above, the dropdown select has the values - Kia, Nissan, Toyota and Honda.  Is it possible to have options with both text and value, like the normal html select?

```
<option value='kia'>Kia Car</option>
```

Answer (score 4):

See https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/blob/b0802f78b5c4fbe0de9a9b9b4b5a013f2364f45a/test/jasmine/spec/editors/selectEditorSpec.js#L100

```
var options = {
  'mit' : 'Misubishi',
  'che' : 'Chevrolet',
  'lam' : 'Lamborgini'
};

handsontable({
  columns: [
    {
      editor: 'select',
      selectOptions: options
    }
  ]
});
```

And the select result is the key.

Answer (score 0):

After browsing docs I couldn't find some built-in method of doing that, so it looks like this by default:

```
<select class="htSelectEditor" style="height: 24px; min-width: 50px; top: 26px; left: 50px; margin: 0px;">
<option value="Kia">Kia</option>
<option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
<option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
<option value="Honda">Honda</option>
</select>
```

But you could manipulate it with JQuery - after rendering - just looping through select options and rewrite value attr. if you really need to change them, I suppose.